# Can't seem to brace when squat is on back

Tags: squats, breathing

I am trying to do the Valsalva Maneveur when I squat. It seems so that I find it difficult to do it when the weight is on the back, but find it easy to do when I am in a rested state (eg: writing this question).

What can I do to improve?

Answer (score 1):

#### Shrug your shoulders a bit.

I had the same experience you are having. With my shoulders relaxed, my trunk muscles are already working to bear the load of the bar on my back, in response to the spinal compression. Shrugging your shoulders a bit, lifting the weight up, thereby decompressing the spine, will allow you to relax your trunk so you can get a proper brace.